# How to write shell scripts in Sun Solaris?

Tags: command-line-interface, ubuntu, solaris, linux

I am new to Unix shell scripting. So can anybody help me?

How to write shell scripts in Sun Solaris? How to run/execute the script?

Please post in detail.

Comment: i have very good skills in C++ language

Comment: Shell scripting is very different to c++ so the learning curve might be quite steep. Check out http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/ its aimed at Linux OS's but the principles are largely the same.

Comment: This is outside the scope of server fault. A common shell to script in is bash - you can find an introduction to bash scripting [here](http://tille.garrels.be/training/bash/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- create script file, first row beginning with this: `#!/bin/sh -`
- add script body (`echo Hello world`) on following lines after that.
- make script executable (`chmod u+x scriptfile`)
- either put scriptfile somewhere in your path, or invoke it by its pathname.

`./scriptfile` is the relative pathname if your current directory is where you put the script.

Answer (score 2):

It is not very different from writing a shell script in Linux. Some pitfalls:

- Relying on GNU tools, but not installed (sed, awk, grep -r etc.)
- Path names (if you use bash, prefix all your scripts with `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

I suggest you to read http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html.